# Add multiple fields to attribute table in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, fields-attributes, iterator

I want to add a number of columns to an attribute table in a few steps using Model Builder.

I think this link gives the answer https://community.esri.com/thread/182530-how-do-i-add-multiple-fields-to-a-table-in-model-builder-arcgis-104 
but I am having trouble replicating it, because I don't understand the basics.

I created a table that has the attributes I want, but I now need to figure out how this fits in the model builder.

I have the layer I am interested in `Property.shp`,

The input to Iterate is `MyTable`, which gives the 2 outputs `I_MyTable` and `Value`.

I don't understand how this links in to Add Field - or if that is even the correct next step.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to utilize the [Iterate Row Selection](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-row-selection.htm) and more information here [examples-of-using-iterators](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6DAC76648FEB466388AD883E141D3960)

[image]

> Iterates over rows in a table.

**Usage**

> This tool is intended for use in ModelBuilder and not in Python scripting.
>
> Iterate Row Selection calls Make Table View to select a table record and creates two outputs: Selected Rows and Value. The output Selected Rows is a Table View and can be used as inputs to other geoprocessing tools that accept a Table View as input in ModelBuilder.
>
> More than one group by field can be used for the selection. If one or more group by fields are selected, the number of iterations is determined by the number of unique combinations of the group by fields. For each iteration, the selection of the output feature layer is determined by the number of records that match the given combination of the group by fields. If more than one group by field is chosen, then the values are concatenated _ in the output inline variable name. See an example below where two group fields: CALL_TYPE and Crime_Peri (crime period) are used. The output Value is Vandalism_Morning and so on for the other values.

[image]